# Python Selenium Firefox understand error message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a test script in Python Selenium Firefox and seemingly at random it crashes with the following error...

```
 Time Elapsed: 104.31666666666666
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sel_scripts\main.py", line 110, in <module>
    source_rf_script(driver, time, randint)


  File "D:\sel_scripts\data_sources\myscript.py", line 184, in source_rf_script
    htmlText = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")


  File "C:\Users\user4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']


  File "C:\Users\user4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)


  File "C:\Users\user4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)


selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: waiting for doc.body failed

Stacktrace:
    at injectAndExecuteScript/< (file:///C:/Users/user4/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpvbvr8pjg/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:
10678)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g (file:///C:/Users/user4/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpvbvr8pjg/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver
-component.js:629)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/user4/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpvbvr8pjg/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/
driver-component.js:623)
```

I am trying to work out what is causing it, to me it reads like the driver.execute_script command is causing the failure.  Could it be when the page elements fail to load correctly (which happens occasionally on the dev server) and the command is unable to find any?

Am I reading it right?

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code related to initializing the driver, navigating and anything happening before this `execute_script`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [find that error](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/firefox-driver/js/firefoxDriver.js#L259) in the JavaScript source.

The logic seems to be that [whenever someone calls](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/firefox-driver/js/firefoxDriver.js#L212) `execute_script()`, i.e. on the line:

```
htmlText = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

... a listener waits [up to 10 seconds](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/firefox-driver/js/firefoxDriver.js#L345) for a `<body>` element to (yet) be available in the current document. If one doesn't, you get the error.

I believe the motivation is to alert you that the execution of a very slow script - and trying to grab the `innerHtml` of the entire doc *will* be slow - may have blocked the loading of the document that invoked it.

So, two possibilities:

- If, as you say, the DOM never loads, then that could misleadingly trigger the error (though it's reasonable to get some kind of error).
- Or it could still be a race condition, i.e. DOM loading blocked by misbehaving script.

Solutions would be:

- Avoid executing any scripts until you know the DOM exists and is ready.
- Find a smarter, quicker way to get the data from the page.
- (Obviously you have a right to expect that the page you're testing will be served correctly from the back-end.)

See also this thread: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1157